# BeanDefinitionStoreException with Play framework

Tags: spring, playframework

I get this exception when trying to get to first page of my website.

```
Oops: BeanDefinitionStoreException
An unexpected error occured caused by exception BeanDefinitionStoreException: I/O failure during classpath scanning; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/mmm/Documents/work/workspace/BCR/precompiled/java/app/config/AppConfig$WebserviceMode.class (No such file or directory)

play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Unexpected Error
    at play.Play.start(Play.java:545)
```

I'm using Spring 1.0.2 and Play 1.2.4
Can you please help me on this? I searched the internet but couldn't get a clear response!

Comment: I fixed the problem by removing an extra attribute 'xsi' in my application-context.xml on <bean>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by removing an extra attribute 'xsi' in my application-context.xml on

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are hitting this issue : https://github.com/pepite/Play--framework-Spring-module/pull/9

Try `play compile` before starting your app.

Comment: Thanks. Actually after adding `play.spring.namespace-aware=true` then it complained about **xsi** attribute in **application-context.xml** and then I removed that extra xsi and now it works fine